# Third-Party Static Frameworks within a XCode Framework Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode5, static-libraries

I have created a iOS Framework using the iOS-Universal-Framework:

https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

When I use a static library, let's say *libGoogleAnalytics.a* I can build my framework let's say *MyObjectiveCLib.framework* and put everything into the main app. The static libraries will be properly linked into the app.

As soon as I try to add another Third-Party static framework, let's say *WindowsAzureMessaging.framework* to the framework project, I cannot build the app if I don't link this framework against the app too.

So I'm going to have the *WindowsAzureMessaging.framework* twice within the iOS app and within the app's core framework *MyObjectiveCLib.framework*

A solution that I have found is to build every imported framework as a static library (of course we are talking about static libraries in all cases, since it's all about static libs in iOS, hence in this case we are talking about a static framework).

Anyway I cannot do this for every framework when I do not have the source libraries for them.

Answer (score 0):

So since iOS8 release I was able to compile and run the Embedded Frameworks:
Look at my post [XCode 6 and Embedded Frameworks only supported in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909870/xcode-6-and-embedded-frameworks-only-supported-in-ios8/25910262#25910262)